# Do all physical equations have a polynomial and a non-polynomial part?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Let $Q,Q_1,...,Q_n$ be $n+1$ physical quantities associated with some physical dimensions. Assume, the physical equation

$$Q = f(Q_1,...,Q_n) $$

is true.
While discussing methods of dimensional analysis, my professor noted, that all physical equations of the above form can be written as

$$Q = \tilde{f}(Q_1,...,Q_n) Q_1^{p_1}...Q_n^{p_n}$$

for some real exponents $p_1,...,p_n$.

Is this true? Why should this be the case? So far, I have a very hard time, wrapping my mind around dimensional analysis.

Comment: What is $\tilde{f}(Q_1,...,Q_n)$?

Comment: This is not a mathematical statement. You need some kind of physical postulates.

Comment: The professor was probably referring to [Buckingham π theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem).

Comment: The only physical postulate seems to be that the dimension on the left and right side of the equation is the same.

Comment: This obviously does not work as written if $p_1\neq 0$ and there is any combination of values of $Q,Q_2,\ldots,Q_n$ for which $Q \neq 0$ and $Q=f(0,Q_2,\ldots,Q_n).$ I think there are some implicit additional assumptions.